# *GAS* Create headers from an array of strings in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create two headers in Google Sheets with GAS.

I would like to write to each cell starting at A1 write the first string in the array "values" then move on to cell B1 and write the second string in array "values". And so on depending on the size of the array "values".

What am I doing wrong?

```
function formatSheet(){
    var name =  "Formatted Sheet";
    var values = [["Description", "Quantity"]];
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
    ss.renameActiveSheet(name);
    createHeaders(name,values);
}

function createHeaders(name,values){
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);  

    for(var i = 1; i < values.length; ++i){
        for(j=0; j<values.length; ++j){
            //create the headers
            sheet.getRange(1, i).setValues(values[j]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your thoughts were helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but it looks like you've over-complicated things. If you're only setting the headers, you know that there will only be 1 array inside the values array - which means you can do away with the for loops and just grab the length of the first array inside. See my example:

```
function formatSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name =  "Format2";
  var values = [["Description", "Quantity"]];
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
  ss.renameActiveSheet(name);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var cols = values[0].length;
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, cols).setValues(values);
}
```

It would also be helpful to know what error you were getting.

Comment: I was over complicating it. That did the trick, thanks. I wasn't getting an error and for whatever reason the debugger wasn't pulling up on that function. I was getting nothing that I knew of.

Answer (score 0):

modifed Jens Astrup's solution  to insert  headers to currently active spreadsheet

```
function SetHeadersToActiveSheet(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var values = [["Description", "Quantity", "Amount"]];
    var cols = values[0].length;
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1,cols).setValues(values);
}
```